Mapping URLs with a dynamic prefix
I am working on a country selection issue. I want my home page to render 2 different views. If they are a new user, they will have to select a country. If not, they will be moved to the home page with a /us or /any-country as the pathname

I'm using nextjs 14.1.0 and also using next-intl for localization but i use the localePrefix: 'never' option to avoid showing the localization prefix

I'm trying to achieve that functionality with parallel routing and modifying the middleware which is not working very well
Is there a better method?
This is how I structure my folders:

Locale layout
import { Viewport } from 'next';
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import IntlProvider from '@/contexts/intl.provider';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { COUNTRY_COOKIE } from '@/i18n/routing';

export const viewport: Viewport = {
  themeColor: "#fff"
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  params,
  home,
  country,
}: {
  params: { locale: string };
  home: React.ReactNode;
  country: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const cookieStore = cookies()

  return (
    <html lang={params.locale}>
      <body>
        <IntlProvider>
          {cookieStore.get(COUNTRY_COOKIE) ? (
            home
          ) : (
            country
          )}
        </IntlProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

middleware.ts
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const publicPathnameRegex = RegExp(
    `^(/(${locales.join('|')}))?(${publicPages
      .flatMap((p) => (p === '/' ? ['', '/'] : p))
      .join(
        '|'
      )}|\/(product|category|supplier|brand|collection|auth\/forget-password)?\/[^\/]+)?$`,
    'i'
  );
  const isPublicPage = publicPathnameRegex.test(
    req.nextUrl.pathname.split(countryPrefix[0])[1] ??
      req.nextUrl.pathname.split(countryPrefix[0])[0]
  );
  const selectedCountry = req.cookies.get(COUNTRY_COOKIE);
  if (selectedCountry) {
    if (isPublicPage) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(req.nextUrl.pathname, req.url));
    } else {
      return (authMiddleware as any)(req);
    }
  } else {
    return intlMiddleware(req);
  }
}

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)', '/', '/:path*'],
};

intl-config
export const routing = defineRouting({
  // A list of all locales that are supported
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],

  // Used when no locale matches
  defaultLocale: 'en',

  localePrefix: 'never',
});

I tried to also edit next.config.js but I can't seem to find way to read the cookie to get the selected country value
next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: '/should-read-from-cookie/:path*'
      }
    ]
  },
}


You say you are using the next-intl to get localization but its set to never, does it still get the value you were wanting, such as US or /othercountry ?  What is failing exactly then if you got the country code and you try to add it to the url, how is it failing exactly?

For next-intl, yes the localization still works, I want to replace the localization prefix with a separate country code prefix that's why it is set to never.

What i want to achieve is that after the user selects a country, a custom prefix will be appended to the url which is not the same prefix as the localization prefix. hope this explains what i want

I know this sounds tedious but what if you built something to convert the values from the prefix that doesn't work to the intended result?  Sure its dozens of countries in the world, but after you are done, you could reuse that list for your future projects.  Not sure what the equvilent of a SELECT CASE is in react, but that would allow you supply a value and get the result quickly even in a decent sized list.

Yes, I am trying to achieve that behavior but it is proving to be quite difficult in nextjs. I saved the selected country value in a cookie, but I'm not sure how to append that cookie to the url immediately when the user opens the site

Ok so you have the convert part done, you just need a way to update the url location?  Can you do a redirect to that new url perhaps on event of a change to the country value or something along those lines.  Real quick though, do you have directories for each country already?  Or are you trying to just make it SAY that location in the url? Cause the second is a URL rewrite instead of a redirection.

Yeh, when the user selects the country it pushes to the new country url (i.e /us, ...)
and then saves the country to a cookie. But the problem, I'm trying to solve is when the user re-opens the site and they already has that cookie value, I want the app to redirect to that country

If you have the value in the cookie, put in some logic to first look for that cookie and then do the redirect and if the cookie isn't there, do the normal logic that you already have that does the url redirect,  and sets the cookie value.
